# Does PyCharm's Database Tool support to access Amazon DynamoDB and RDS?

Tags: pycharm, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, jetbrains-ide

I daily use Pycharm as my primary python IDE. My projects use Boto (Amazon Python SDK) to access Amazon DynamoDB and Amazon RDS. Does any one has experience to make Pycharm works with Amazon's Database service?

I think if I can view and show table content of RDS and search the data of DynamoDB directly from Pycharm would be pretty neat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can by using the Redshift JDBC driver provided by AWS along with a custom driver definition in the IDE.

To setup the Redshift driver

- Download the Redshift JDBC drivers from [AWS Redshift driver documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html)
- In Pycharm (or any Idea based IDE) Open the *Data Sources and Drivers* dialog by either selecting a datasource from the new datasource menu (click the "+" in the top toolbar of the Database panel).
- From the *New* menu (click the "+" in the top left toolbar of the dialog) select the *Driver* option (is near the bottom).
- From the *driver files* panel add the JAR file that was downloaded in the first step.
- Select `com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver` from the *Class* dropdown.
- Select *PostgreSQL* from the *Dialect* dropdown.
- Add a URL template: `jdbc:redshift://{host}:{port}/{database}`
- Finally hit apply

To use the driver:

- From the *New* menu (click the "+" in the top left toolbar of the dialog) select the newly added driver.
- Add connection details from the AWS console for your Redshift cluster.
- Use port 4536

Comment: Is Redshift driver usable with DynamoDB and RDS in question?

Comment: With DynamoDB no, it's a completely different style of database. You possibly could use it with an RDS PostgreSQL (Redshift is based on the PostgreSQL protocol). However, there are native drivers for all RDS database types, better to just use those.

Comment: Do you know what the default username and password is?

Comment: @Robbo_UK the master username and password are set on the creation of the Redshift cluster.

Comment: The question talks about DynamoDB and the answer about Redshift. Why is this answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
You just need to add a new driver definition and add to driver files the Jar drivers you can download from AWS Console redshift.

Set class name to com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver
Set url template as jdbc:redshift://{host}:{port}/{database}
Set default port to 4539
Set default dialect to PostgreSQL

You can use now connections using this driver that work super fine.

Comment: The drivers are available from here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/configure-jdbc-connection.html

Comment: What does Redshift have to do with Dynamodb?